# Spring jdbc:initialize-database not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, hsqldb

I can't get spring to initialize my database, although from what I can see I'm doing this right. I keep getting a org/springframework/dao/DataAccessResourceFailureException.

Here is my springapp-servlet.xml:

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>



<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" ignore-failures="DROPS">
<jdbc:script location="classpath:create_products.sql" />
<jdbc:script location="classpath:load_data.sql" />
 </jdbc:initialize-database>
```

The jdbc.properties file is in Java Resources/src and is this:

```
 jdbc.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
 jdbc.url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost
 jdbc.username=sa
 jdbc.password=
```

The create_products.sql is also in Java Resources/src and is this:
    CREATE TABLE products (
      id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      description varchar(255),
      price decimal(15,2)
     );

The load_data.sql is in the same location and is this:

```
INSERT INTO products (id, description, price) values(1, 'Lamp', 5.78);
INSERT INTO products (id, description, price) values(2, 'Table', 75.29);
INSERT INTO products (id, description, price) values(3, 'Chair', 22.81);
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend Hibernate for this task.. but if you can't,I think the best advice I can give is to get the log4j and make some logging.With a full stacktrace,might be there's someone will know what happens.

Comment: Apart from initialisation, can you access the DB? With your jdbc.url you need to start the HSQLDB server separately before running your code.

Comment: @Dave : where is the location of your spring configuration file 'springapp-servlet.xml' ?

Answer (score 0):

Dave probably you are also getting this error in your springapp-servlet.xml `cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'jdbc:initialize-database' is not complete. 
 One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc":script}' is expected.` ?

The org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init package provides support for initializing an existing DataSource. Just check if your spring-jdbc version. 
Ref: `[http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch12s09.html][1]`

Just open the spring-jdbc jar and see under: `org/springframework/jdbc/datasource` if you can see any folder by name `init` .If `init` folder doesnt exist, then the version of Spring Framework you are using does not support this feature.

[image]